# Verb personal endings in present tense where stem ends in m or n

Tags: verb

Most grammar references that I have seen state that if a verb stem ends with m or n, and is not preceded with the consonants l or r, then in the Present Tense the 2nd person singular ending becomes -est, and the 3rd person singular and 2nd person plural ending becomes -et.  But I see some verbs (kommen, kennen, schwimmen for example) where this is not apparently the case.  Is there another rule that I should be aware of?  Or is this an example of natural variability in the language and one must just learn these exceptions?

Comment: It sound very archaic to me. The Christmas carol "Ihr Kinderlein, kommet" actually makes use of the rule. Do you have another example for a verb where it's supposed to be like this? Können also does not follow this rule.

Answer (score 4):

You misinterpreted this rule. Double consonants are a peculiarity of written German. They are used as a marker the previous vowel should be short. For speech matters —and that inserted schwa is just a matter of speech— they are single consonants. The reason for this schwa is avoiding hard to pronounce consonant clusters:

> regnen → du regnest, ihr regnet *(not: du regnst, ihr regnt)*
>
> atmen → du atmest, ihr atmet *(not: to atmst, ihr atmt)*

With vowel-preceded consonants, this isn't a problem:

> klonen → du klonst, ihr klont *(-onst and -ont are easy to pronounce)*
>
> stemmen → du stemmst, ihr stemmt *(-emmst and -emmt are easy to pronounce)*

Let's try with some verbs that don't exist (yet).

> prülmen → du prülmst, ihr prülmt
>
> sutmen → du sutmest, ihr sutmet. *(How do you pronounce sutmst? Or sutmt?)*

See how this works? The schwa is needed for pronunciation.

Comment: Although what counts as "easy to pronounce" is another question. Do foreign speakers really find "prülmst" easy to pronounce? Probably it's actually about the first consonant being a stop.

Comment: Ah thanks I can see now the double consonant pattern.  And have read up on and more informed about the schwa, the sound of which occurs often in many languages but is a term I had not come across before.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @CJSMelb: There're actually two schwa-sounds in German. One is the same as in English, you will find it in reduction syllables written with an -e-. The other is *Tiefschwa*, a reduced variant of the *a*, you will find it written as -r- or -er- at many syllable ends.